# How to kill only if process is running?

Tags: bash, command-line, kill

Currently, I use a line like this in my sh script file:

```
kill $(ps aux | grep -F 'myServer' | grep -v -F 'grep' | awk '{ print $2 }')
```

But I wonder how to call it only if process (`myServer` here) is running?

Comment: it's impossible to call `kill` only when the process is running, because there is a race condition between the test and the invocation of `kill` (it's possible the process stopped for another reason in that short time).  You should use `pkill` or `killall` which do exactly the same as what you try to do, but with less to type (and probably some other advantages too).

Comment: Related: [How to let 'kill' ignore processes that are not alive](https://superuser.com/a/155915/500826). Also, you can avoid ps+grep x2 with `pgrep`

Answer (score 33):

I usually just use pgrep and pkill

```
if pgrep myServer; then pkill myServer; fi
```

Comment: Why not `pkill myServer` or `killall -q myServer`? There's no downside to attempting to kill inexistent processes.

Comment: It will not exit 0 if there is no process to kill, so it could break scripts.

Comment: Append `|| true` then.

Comment: True, but you won't have the flexibility to add a else to inform you the process was already dead.

Comment: What about `if ! killall -q myServer; then echo ERROR; fi`?

Comment: @DavidFoerster: the `|| true` top is excellent, thanks!

Answer (score 10):

You could kill processes by name using `pkill` or `killall`, check their man pages.

Comment: yes, unlike `kill`, this kills only if process is running. For example `pkill -u myuser -f myprocess\.[0-9]+`

Answer (score 9):

A bit of a different approach would be something like this:

```
killall PROCESS || echo "Process was not running."
```

This will avoid the `1` Error-Code returned from the `killall` command, if the process did not exist. The `echo` part will only come into action, if `killall` returns `1`, while itself will return `0` (success).

Comment: Using `killall -q` is better

Comment: Warning, `killall -q` isn't supported on all unix flavors, macOS Catalina still doesn't have it.

Comment: @tresf my ubuntu distribution doesn't have it either

Answer (score 1):

Small Script I have created with R&D. I hope you will like it

```bash
#!/bin/bash

echo "Enter the process name:"
read $proc_name
if pgrep $proc_name; then
  echo "$proc_name running "
  pkill $proc_name
  echo "$proc_name got killed"
else
  echo "$proc_name is not running/stopped "
fi
```

save it with some name like `script.sh`
then

```
chmod +x script.sh
./script.sh
```

Then give your process name.

**Note**: I have tried many times with this and its fine.

Comment: May I know whats wrong with this script and -ve vote needs an explanation please.

Comment: Nothing wrong with this script... +1

Answer (score 1):

Check if the process exist with `pidof`. If it does, kill it:

```
(! pidof process_name) || sudo kill -9 $(pidof process_name)
```

Exit code is always 0 after executing the above command.

Answer (score 1):

Use `pkill` with option `-f`

```
pkill -f myServer
```

Option `-f` is the pattern that is normally matched against the process name.

Comment: You can also put `-2` before `-f` to shut the process down more gracefully (same as pressing Ctrl + C).

Answer (score 0):

```
pkill -9 -f jboss || true
```

or

```
pkill -9 -f tomcat || true
```

Answer (score -1):

try using:

```
sudo kill `pidof process_name`
```

where process_name is the name of the process you want to kill. What's great about this is that pidof will list the pid's of all processes matching the given name. Since kill accepts multiple pid's, it will kill of all of them in a single whim.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: What if list is empty? (my main point was not to call kill at all if possible)

Comment: If the list is empty, kill will return an error code 1 and not kill anything. It would be the equivalent as trying to call kill with no arguments. You could add an if statement that first checks if pidof returns an empty list. If it does not return an empty list, call ``kill `pidof process_name``. If it does return an empty list, skip the kill call.

Answer (score -1):

I would use:

```
ps x --no-header -o pid,cmd | awk '!/awk/&&/myServer/{print $1}' | xargs -r kill
```

The `xargs -r` tells to run kill only if there is input.  The `ps --no-header -eo pid,cmd` gets the output into a better format for parsing.